# Syntax error when inserting bytes array into sqlite table

Tags: android, sqlite

i'm trying to store objects from a recycler view as blobs inside my sqlite database
i've created a table

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS favorites(id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, obj BLOB);");
```

then i get the wanted object from the arraylist of items
and using the Gson library i convert it to json and then get the bytes array from it

and then store it in the table, but i'm getting a syntax error at the bytes array itself in sqlite

```
Gson g=new Gson();
try{
db.execSQL("insert into favorites (obj) values'" + g.toJson(items.get(getAdapterPosition())).getBytes()+"';");
}catch (Exception e){
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

here is the error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "'[B@e728d17'": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: insert into favorites (obj) values '[B@e728d17';
```

if i don't encase it in single quotation marks i get unrecognized token error

```
W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "[B@e728d17;" (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: insert into favorites (obj) values [B@e728d17;
```

Comment: no this is not what i'm looking for

Comment: I don't understand (obj) can u explain what is it supposed to do?

Comment: obj is a column in the table of "datatype" blob, this is where i want to store my bytes array that represents the object

Comment: there is a ' where values ends. syntax error
insert into favorites (obj) values'

Comment: it is to encase it in single quotation..if not done i get unrecognized token error, read the post

Answer (score 0):

try to use method with arguments:

```
    try{
        db.execSQL("insert into favorites (obj) values (?)", 
                     new Object[]{g.toJson(items.get(getAdapterPosition())).getBytes()});
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: required object[]
 provided byte[]

Comment: i don't understand your answer..why would i cast my byte array to object array?
how am i supposed to deal with it when i want to retrieve it for the database?